# Google Sheets Number not being able to find rational approximation of number?

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting

I am trying to rationalize the numbers in one of my spreadsheets just out of curiosity, using the number format "###############/###############" as I wanted a one-size-fits-all format. This obviously does not work too well for very big, or very small numbers, but I figured it should work well for 'moderately' sized numbers.
It works quite well in most cases, but there are a few numbers where I would've expected it to work, but it just displays "#VALUE!"

- 1049126.75
- 1981684.75
- 3170696.2

Google Sheet has no issues with finding the correct form when using the number format "###############/#", but it seems like it is not able to find it when allowing too many digits in the denominator.

How to solve this issue? Do I really need to manually enter a good approximation of the expected numbers of digits in the denominator for each number separately?

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Write any of the numbers above in a cell
2. Go to "Format > Custom Number Format" and enter the custom number format "###############/###############"

Comment: @BlindSpots Thank you for considering the issue, I added reproduction instructions

Comment: @BlindSpots Interesting, that the first two work for you. The third one should be "15853481/5", as can be seen when using the number format "############/#". There is not really a reason for me to do this, I just played around and was wondering why this wouldn't work properly

Comment: @BlindSpots To me it seems like, that "#/#" only checks for denominators with 1 digit, so if you were to enter "=19/12" in a cell and format it with "#/#", then it would display something incorrect because 19/12 cannot be simplified any further. After a few tries, it looks like the amount of hashtags in the numerator does not matter though, so these ones is indeed irrelevant..

Comment: Isn't this just a floating point thing?